# Groovy XmlParser -> Needs to be closed?

Tags: file-io, groovy, release

I am reading a xml- file with the groovy XmlParser e.g.:

```
def myXMLContent = new XmlParser().parse(new File("myFile.xml"))
```

But I don't find a close Method for the XmlParser. Don't I have to release the filehandle? I did not find anything in the docs about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [groovy wraps the file](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/XmlParser.java#L114) like `new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file))`, and passes it to the parser.

And as it says in the [API docs for InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html):

> ...standard processing of both byte and character streams is to close them on as part of end-of-parse cleanup, so applications should not attempt to re-use such streams after they have been handed to a parser.